# jQuery Confirm on click of button

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the following code that works in conjunction with a "value" that is given from data inputted into an `input` box.

How would I alter this code to just send the data - `product_details['id']` without the need for `input` data?

**Example jQuery Code:**

```
    $('body').on("click", "#product_change_set_order_btn", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var box = $("#product_set_order_box");
        var id = box.data("id"); 

        var url = box.data("url");              
        var data_array = { 
                id : id, 
                new_sort : box.val(), 
            };

        if($.trim(box.val()) != "")
        {
            ajaxCall(url, data_array, null, "product_set_order");

            alert("Your Sort Order Has Been Set");
        }

    });
```

**HTML Button:**

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete <?php echo $product_details['name']; ?>" data-name="<?php echo $product_details['name']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $product_details['id']; ?>" data-url="admin/PS_products/ajax_product_delete">Delete <?php echo $product_details['name']; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $('body').on("click", "#product_change_set_order_btn", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var box = $("#product_set_order_box");
        var id = box.data("id"); 

        var url = box.data("url");              
        var data_array = { 
                id : id, 
                new_sort : box.val(), 
            };

            ajaxCall(url, data_array, null, "product_set_order");

            alert("Your Sort Order Has Been Set");

    });
```